# Curl get request in Ruby

Tags: ruby, curl

Would be very grateful if someone could help me convert this curl request into ruby?I have Been trying for a while and can't get the syntax correct.

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Knack-Application-Id:000000" -H "X-Knack-REST-API-Key:000000" https://api.knackhq.com/v1/objects/object_6/records
```

tried:

```
uri = URI('https://api.knackhq.com/v1/objects/object_1/records')


Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
              :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
                      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri

                      # API details of Knack
                      request["X-Knack-Application-Id"] = '56e72cd003219158'
                      request["X-Knack-REST-API-Key"] = 'd9c343d2-2a4b-291e0712a63a'

            end
```

Comment: A little code formatting wouldn't hurt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two issues.

First, in the `cURL` command you don't specify a method, hence by default it is a `GET`, but you use `POST` in Ruby.

Secondly, you are missing the part where you execute the HTTP request

```
http.request(request)
```

Here's the code:

```
uri = URI('https://api.knackhq.com/v1/objects/object_1/records')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req["X-Knack-Application-Id"] = '56e72cd003219158'
req["X-Knack-REST-API-Key"] = 'd9c343d2-2a4b-291e0712a63a'

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
  http.request(req)
end
```

More examples are available in the [`Net::HTTP` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).

Comment: This is what I was trying to achieve but I'm now getting the following error: 
     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1861:in `initialize': undefined method `empty?' for #<URI::HTTPS:0x00000000bcfca0> (NoMethodError)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try some gems? I often use RestClient for api reqests, here is my example:

`RestClient.post("https://api.knackhq.com/v1/objects/object_6/records", {}, {"X-Knack-REST-API-Key" => "000000", "X-Knack-Application-Id"=>"000000"})`

More information about: https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client